# Send mail without saving in users sent items

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is it possible to send mail without saving a copy in the user's sent items? I am using MFMessage framework.

Answer (score 0):

NO if you want to use MFMessage framework, it is not possible to send email without sending in user's sent items.

BTW why would you like to do this ? Any way, if you are using user's account, you CANT.

But then if you want an email to be sent, use smtp and other account, that is highly undesirable

Comment: smtp most probably would end up as spam I guess.

Comment: You need to confingure it properly, I used with Php, never tried with iphone, but if you add sender's mail details in it's config, it wont go in spam, but for iphone I dont think so you should use that.

Comment: I want to do this to stop misusage of email id by user.

Comment: How you can stop misusage, I feel you can misuse user's email id since you dont want to show him mail sent from your app

Comment: I am sending precoded text from users mail. If user get the email id he would send some unwanted mails to it which I want to stop.

Comment: For that you can do one thing, call webservice that can send mail. It is highly secured

Comment: web service ? never used one. It would help me if you send some links from where I can learn about them.

Comment: Refer this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-interacting-with-web-services/

Comment: Its about downloading which I have implemented lot , but nothing about email :(

Comment: Oh you didnt understood what I meant, Webservice is a means that you will call from api and that webservice inturn send email from web, this is how you need to implement